# confusing behavior of LSB Init Scripts in Debian

Tags: debian, init-script, lsb

I am experiencing strange behavior with LSB Init Scripts in Debian Wheezy. I can demonstrate the problem on following example:

The script `/etc/init.d/resolvconf` starts in `S` and stops in runlevels `0` and `6`.

```
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      0 6
```

And indeed, when I use `chkconfig resolvconf on` to turn the script on, I see that symlinks have been created in respective runlevel directories:

```
$ ls /etc/rc?.d/*resolvconf
/etc/rc0.d/K02resolvconf
/etc/rc6.d/K02resolvconf
/etc/rcS.d/S13resolvconf
```

When I turn the script off with `chkconfig resolvconf off`, the symlinks disappear. So far so good.

Now, I have decided I don't want the script to start in `S` (I am going to start it manually), but I still want it to stop in runlevels `0` and `6`. I change default start accordingly:

```
# Default-Start:     
# Default-Stop:      0 6
```

and turn the script on `chkconfig resolvconf on`. And nothing happens.

```
$ ls /etc/rc?.d/*resolvconf
ls: cannot access /etc/rc?.d/*resolvconf: No such file or directory
```

no symlinks have been created, and the script does not stop in runlevels `0` and `6`.

What is happening here?

How can I have a script only run (stop) in runlevels `0` and `6`, without starting in `S` ?

## UPDATE

as suggested by @Rui F Ribeiro, I have completely removed the `# Default-Start:` line. Now when I run `chkconfig resolvconf on`, I get following errors:

```
insserv: Script resolvconf is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `resolvconf'
```

the symlinks are created, though.

```
$ ls /etc/rc?.d/*resolvconf
/etc/rc0.d/K02resolvconf
/etc/rc6.d/K02resolvconf
```

But why do I get the errors?

Comment: When there is no start, chkconfig knows that it haven't to be stopped. Create them if you want!
`ln -s /etc/init.d/resolvconf /etc/rc6.d/K02resolvconf && ln -s /etc/init.d/resolvconf /etc/rc0.d/K02resolvconf`

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro - I have updated my original question.

Comment: The messages come from `insserv`; in Debian, `chkconfig` is just a front-end to that. In LSB, "Default-Start" is required, so the messages are correct; what isn't is the behaviour with an empty "Default-Start" (your first test). Could you run `insserv -v resolvconf` (with the empty "Default-Start" line in the script)? That should give you more information about what's going on...

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - `insserv -v resolvconf` works without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chkconfig` [only reads the "Default-Start" lines](http://sources.debian.net/src/chkconfig/11.4-54.60.1-1/chkconfig/#L76) when calculating the runlevels for scripts. It counts the number of runlevels and only calls `insserv` [if at least one runlevel is requested](http://sources.debian.net/src/chkconfig/11.4-54.60.1-1/chkconfig/#L662) in "Default-Start"...

Workarounds which avoid this behaviour include:

- enabling services with `chkconfig -a`;
- disabling services with `chkconfig -d`;
- using `insserv` directly, `insserv service` to enable `service`, `insserv -r service` to remove it.